# Entity Framework Core is not saving related/sub entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Normally, Entity Framework Core should save related data of an entity automatically. In my case, I have this `Team` class I want to save:

```
using Domain;
using Sandwich.Domain.Interfaces;
using Sandwich.Domain.Interfaces.Factory;

namespace Sandwich.Domain
{
    internal class Team : Entity, ITeam
    {
        public Guid TeamId { get; private set; }
        public string TeamName { get; private set; }
        public IReadOnlyList<ITeamMember> TeamMembers { get => _teamMembers; }
        public IRepresentative Representative { get => _representative; }

        private readonly List<TeamMember> _teamMembers;
        private Representative _representative = null!;

        private Team(Guid teamId, string teamName)
        {
            _teamMembers = new List<TeamMember>();
            TeamId = teamId;
            TeamName = teamName;
        }

        // methods and other logic...
    }
}
```

I would like Entity Framework Core to automatically also save the `TeamMembers` and `Representative` entities. I would like to achieve this by only calling `_dbContext.Add(team);`.

Here is the code for that:

```
using Sandwich.Applogic;
using Sandwich.Domain.Interfaces;

namespace Sandwich.Infrastructure
{
    internal class TeamDbRepository : ITeamRepository
    {
        private readonly SandwichContext _context;

        public TeamDbRepository(SandwichContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task SaveNewTeamAsync(ITeam team)
        {
            await _context.AddAsync(team);
            /*
            Right now I have to also run this code for the entities to be saved in the database. 
            Otherwise only the Team entity and its id and name are saved.
            foreach (ITeamMember teamMember in team.TeamMembers) {
                await _context.AddAsync(teamMember);
            }
            */
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried explicitly configuring my entities using `modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany<TeamMember>();` I'm not sure but I think it might have to do something with the usage of interfaces, but I don't know how to resolve this issue. Below are some more classes for context.

Here is my `DbContext` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sandwich.Domain;

namespace Sandwich.Infrastructure
{
    internal class SandwichContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Representative> Representatives { get; set; } = null!;

        public SandwichContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //config/override settings of entities stored in the DB
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            new TeamConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Team>());
            new TeamMemberConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<TeamMember>());
            new RepresentativeConfiguration().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Representative>());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the interface that is passed in to save a `Team` object:

```
namespace Sandwich.Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITeam
    {
        Guid TeamId { get; }
        string TeamName { get; }
        IRepresentative Representative { get; }
        IReadOnlyList<ITeamMember> TeamMembers { get; }
    }
}
```

Finally is the configuration of the entities:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sandwich.Domain;

namespace Sandwich.Infrastructure
{
    internal class TeamConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(t => t.TeamName).IsRequired();
            builder.HasKey(t => t.TeamId);
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sandwich.Domain;

namespace Sandwich.Infrastructure
{
    internal class TeamMemberConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<TeamMember>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TeamMember> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            builder.Property(t => t.FirstName).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(t => t.LastName).IsRequired();
        }

    }
}
//The config for the Representative class is the same as for the TeamMember class.
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you share `TeamConfiguration` and `TeamMemberConfiguration` types?

Comment: The configurations only define the key of every entity and wich property is required. Nothing more. Like this basically:
 `builder.Property(t => t.TeamName).IsRequired(); builder.HasKey(t => t.TeamId);`

Comment: Well, post it as you have to configure relationship in there for entities. Also add `ITeam` interface. Without it it is quite impossible to help.

Comment: Probably because you have added not `Team`, but interface `ITeam`. Cast to `Team` when add entity to context.

Answer (score 0):

I would change how the configurations apply. (might not make a difference, it is just my preference)

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   //config/override settings of entities stored in the DB
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TeamConfiguration());
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TeamMemberConfiguration());
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RepresentativeConfiguration());
}
```

Then you have to change entity objects.

```cs
namespace Sandwich.Domain.Models
{
    public class Team
    {
        Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        ...
        Representative Representative { get; set;  }
        ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set;  }
    }

    public class Representative
    {
        Guid RepresentativeId { get; set; }
        ...
        Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        Team Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class TeamMember
    {
        Guid TeamMemberId { get; set; }
        ...
        Guid TeamId { get; set; }
        Team Team { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I would add relation configuration to parent entity.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Sandwich.Domain;

namespace Sandwich.Infrastructure
{
    internal class TeamConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(t => t.TeamName).IsRequired();
            builder.HasKey(t => t.TeamId);

            modelBuilder
                .HasMany(t => t.TeamMembers)
                .WithOne(tm => tm.Team)
                .HasForeignKey(tm => tm.TeamId)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder
                .HasOne(t => t.Representative)
                .WithOne(r => r.Team)
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.TeamId)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

Maybe it would be better to pass `Team` type into `public async Task SaveNewTeamAsync(Team team)` method.

If you need entities and objects passed into or returned from repository to be different you should do conversion.

Related links:

[ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfiguration?view=efcore-7.0)

[Introduction to relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)